# Dataflow job cost - is there a way to easily get it?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there any information in the developers console (or programatically via the SDK) to retrieve how much a job cost to run on the Dataflow service?

I know that the cost incurred depends on the instance type/count, running time, and other cloud product usages e.g. BigQuery & GCS, but having to calculate that ourselves for each job is not feasible.

Unless I'm missing something obvious, I can't see anything which gives me "Job XYZ cost $x. It cost $x for the worker pool, $x for BigQuery.." etc.

Comment: We are working on more detailed presentation of statistics and costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Dataflow does not expose this functionality at the moment. Your bill includes the aggregated monthly surcharge in a separate line item.

Comment: Is it something that's likely to come in the future?